# How to set the post_thumbnail size to specific category or tag?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create an post gallery grid with different thumbnail sizes. I want to show a different thumbnail size for posts per category. I've added thumbnail sizes in functions.php and tried to conditionally populate the post-thumbnail with custom sizes with the following code:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'thumbvert', 500, 750, true );
add_image_size( 'smallvert', 675, 1013, true );}

if ( in_category( 'thumbvert' )) {
set_post_thumbnail('thumbvert');
} elseif ( in_category( 'smallvert' )) {
set_post_thumbnail('smallvert');
} else {
set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 333 ); }
```

The thumbnails don't change.

Comment: What size is output?

Comment: the output now is 500 x 333

Comment: So none of your conditional are being met as true?

Comment: I guess not. I have no coding skills, I looked it up in the wordpress repository. How do I make the conditionals true?

Comment: First, you'll need to get the current category name if on an archive page. Try the below answer, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Going purely on what  you have supplied. You'll need to get the current category name if on an archive page, then run your conditional. Ex:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
  add_image_size( 'thumbvert', 500, 750, true );
  add_image_size( 'smallvert', 675, 1013, true );
}

if ( is_archive() ) {
  $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
  if ( in_category( $current_category ) ) {
    set_post_thumbnail('thumbvert');
  } elseif ( in_category( $current_category )) {
    set_post_thumbnail('smallvert');
  } else {
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 333 ); 
  }
}
```